# Migrate SQL Server from 2012 to 2014 (11 to 12)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have just installed SQL Server Management studio 2014 and I also need to update my (local) server to accept a new database via a bak file from a version 12 server. When I look in Server Properties I see my server has Version 11.0.5858.0 (which is 2012 sp2).

**How do I upgrade/migrate my server to version 12?**

I've looked at a couple of links: [Upgrade Database Engine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933942.aspx), [Upgrade to SQL Server 2014 Using the Installation Wizard (Setup)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144267.aspx). I've also seen suggestions that I need to backup and restore databases, which I assume would mean creating a new local (I forgotten how to do this, to tell the truth) and moving them there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I have just installed SQL Server Management studio 2014

SSMS wont install database engine. Its just a GUI to connect to SQL Server. You can check the SQL Server version using below T-SQL :

```
SELECT
   SERVERPROPERTY ('MachineName') AS PhysicalMachineName,
   SERVERPROPERTY ('ServerName') AS SQLServerName,
   SERVERPROPERTY ('Edition') AS ServerEdition,
   CAST(SUBSTRING(@@Version,charindex('SQL',@@version, 1),15) AS VARCHAR(255)) +  ' + ' 
       + CAST (SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel')AS VARCHAR (50)) + ' + (Build'
       + CAST (SERVERPROPERTY ('ProductVersion') AS VARCHAR (50)) +')' AS ProductVersion,
    RIGHT(@@version, (Len(@@Version)-charindex('Windows',@@version, 1))+1) AS [O.S.],
 SERVERPROPERTY ('Collation') AS Collation
```

> How do I upgrade/migrate my server to version 12?

There are couple of ways to do.

**InPlace Upgrade** : You just upgrade the current instance by running the setup.exe. The older instance is replaced by the newer version.

**Side by side migration**: You install and configure a new instance that might exist on the same server or different server and then you move all you databases using backup/restore (**preferred**) or other methods like - detach/attach, logshipping, copy database wizard, etc.

**Note**: Depending on your downtime requirements, you have to plan accordingly. Prepare a detailed migration plan and discuss that will stake holders for an acceptable downtime.

*If it is your local instance, then you dont have to worry about any downtime.*

An excellent answer by [Mike Walsh](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/4008/mike-walsh) : [Are SQL Server in-place upgrades as ill advised as they used to be?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/29330/8783)

Also, check out [UPGRADING TO SQL SERVER 2014: A DOZEN THINGS TO CHECK](http://thomaslarock.com/2014/06/upgrading-to-sql-server-2014-a-dozen-things-to-check/) as well as [What to Consider When Creating SQL Server Database Migration Plan?](http://blogs.technet.com/b/meamcs/archive/2013/12/15/what-to-consider-when-creating-sql-server-database-migration-plan.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. My initial confusion was that I only updated the shared parts, rather than the the actual instance (hence I moved from 2012 to 2014 without updating my actual server).